# how can change 24 bit depth to 8 bit depth in python in pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i have a `1.png` and it is `24 bit depth`.i want to convert it to `8 bit depth` with python with pillow.

I tried this code but when i have checked both of these images(1.png and 2.png) were still `24 bit depth`:

```py
from PIL import Image
import os
os.chdir('D:\\test')
img=Image.open('1.png')
img.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=8)
img.save('D:\\test\\2.png')
```

images : [image: images]

How can i convert my 1.png to an 8 bit depth and save it in pillow?

Comment: Where is your image please? And why do you think your code didn't work?

Comment: The 24 bit-depth most likely means 8-bit-depth per channel color (e.g. RGB) image. What you might actually be looking for is a conversion to grayscale. Please clarify what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem but i don't know why previous code did not worked!

I added `img.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=8)` to a new variable.
and saved it with `a.save('D:\\test\\2.png')`

```
from PIL import Image
import os
os.chdir('D:\\hash lip\\test')
img=Image.open('1.png')
a=img.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=8)
a.save('D:\\test\\2.png')
```

Comment: This is because `convert` does not change `img`, it *returns* the converted result. See the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert)

Answer (score 2):

`convert()` doesn't change original image in `img` but it creates new image which you have to assign to variable - if you assign to the same variable `img` then you replace original image.

```
img = img.convert(...)
```

That's all.

Comment: That's the correct answer here.